# How Do You Use jQuery to Simplify Your MVC Views?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have found jQuery to be a great tool to simplify my MVC Views.

For example, instead of including complicated logic to add alternating styles to my tables I just do this...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("table.details tr:odd").addClass("detailsAlternatingRow");
   $("table.details tr:even").addClass("detailsRow");                          
});
```

Do you know of any other good uses of jQuery to slim down the logic in my MVC View?

Comment: What has this to do with MVC?

Comment: Why don't you write:

<tr class="<% rowNumber % 2 == 0 ? "detailsRow" : "detailsAlternatingRow" %> ">

Comment: Because you'd need to code that into every table in every template. You also need to track the rowNumber, the simplicity of which varies from one template language to another. Paco.Comment--

Comment: @ RET: Coding stuff at a different way doesn't mean you have to repeat yourself. Tracking the rownumber is not more difficult then using a for loop instead of a foreach loop. I don't use features from Jquery that can be done server side, because the client load time can be longer the then servers.

Comment: @Paco: The templates are interpreted code. Any performance difference must be negligible, esp. on a page already using jQuery for other things and with the js cached. I didn't say tracking rowNumber was difficult, but why have a dog and bark yourself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MVC Framework has a JsonResult that can be very nice to eliminate server round trips and might be able to get rid of some of the logic in your view page. I wrote a tutorial on this available at :

http://www.dev102.com/2008/08/19/jquery-and-the-aspnet-mvc-framework/

Answer (score 2):

Implementing an observer http://google-ajax-examples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/customevents/jquery.html proved a really good practise.
Really nice for code maintenance.

Answer (score 0):

Note if you use PHP on the server you can use [phpQuery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/) (and I'm sure there are similar server-side jQuery ports for other languages) to do stuff like that without expecting the user to have Javascript enabled.

Comment: Thanks for that link. Doesn't answer the question, but interesting nonetheless